# EditText returns enhanced ISO-8859-1 instead UTF-8 encoding for german umlauts?

Tags: android, utf-8, android-edittext

I am more than just confused. I do have some EditText, and it apparently returns ISO-8859-1 or even mixed 8859-1+UTF8 strings.

My understanding until now was, that Android is fully UTF-8, so this can't even happen.

Examples:
Inputting "wüste" into EditText. A string to hex returns this byte code:
57 fc 73 74 65, my expectation would be: 57 c3bc 73 74 65

Inputting "wüste テスト" returns 57 fc 73 74 65 20 30c6 30b9 30c8, which now even is a mix of extended 8859-1 and UTF-8.

Is this the expected and wanted behaviour? Can I change that somewhere?
I realized this behaviour when sending data using JSON to a server, and that one bailed out because of illegal UTF-8 chars.

Regards,
Oliver

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Java (and therefore Android) strings [are not UTF-8, but UTF-16](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html). The bytes displayed are Unicode code points.

You'll need to convert your string to UTF-8 in order to send it as such (either directly, or via any JSON library you might be using). This can be done by calling `getBytes("UTF8")`
 on your string to get a byte array with the string in the desired encoding.

Comment: Argh, that was not the first time I mixed those utf/unicode things up... Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Actually, the only thing I had to to, was to change
StringEntity(postdata)
to
StringEntity(postdata,HTTP.UTF_8)